# Prove that $2\cos^2(x^3+x) = 2^x + 2^{-x}$ has exactly one solution

Tags: functions, proof-writing

I've been stuck on this question for some time now:

> Show that there is exactly one value of $x$ which satisfies the equation $2\cos^2(x^3+x) = 2^x + 2^{-x}$.

Now this is obviously intuitively correct — I've modelled the equation with a function $f(x) = 2\cos^2(x^3+x) - 2^x - 2^{-x}$, and simply looking at the function reveals that the range of $2\cos^2(x^3+x)$ is $[0,2]$ and the range of $-2^x - 2^{-x}$ is $(-\infty, -2]$. That would imply that $f(x)$ ranges from $(-\infty, 0]$.

What I'm having trouble with is writing down a formal proof based on these intuitive ideas. I have identified $x=0$ as the sole solution; furthermore, I have tried to differentiate the function to find a maximum (a futile endeavor, since the equation becomes messy really quickly).

A hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Move the 2 from the LHS to the denominator of the RHS. The new LHS can not be greater than 1, while the RHS cannot be less than 1(AM-GM). CLearly the only solution is when both are 1 and that occurs only when $x = 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of AM-GM you have

$$2^x + 2^{-x}\geq 2\sqrt{2^x \cdot 2^{-x}}=2$$

where equality holds if and only if $2^x = 2^{-x} \Leftrightarrow x=0$.

Hence, we have

$$2\cos^2{(x^3+x)}\leq 2 < 2^x+2^{-x} \text{ for all } x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$$

Since $x=0$ satisfies the equation, it is the only solution.